# Winforms progressbar display and interrupt

Tags: c#, json, winforms

I have a windows forms application in C#. In this application, i have used a progressbar to show the communication with external web server. How can i update it smoothly while communicating with the web server. the response is a json object(give the request is successful) and i have no access for any other resource in URL. even in case of request error the response is always json object. i want to fill the progress bar while the request is posted to server and json is received in case of a successful response.

PS: i have JSON parse methods to find out if it is a success response and i want to interrupt the progress bar in case the response is not successful.

Comment: what did you tried so far? and sample code please?

Comment: Mention what environment you are working on also please.

Comment: VS 2010 .net 4.0 c# windows forms application. I have tried standard prograss bar using step and performStep. but that is not useful to me in my present context.